# D3 - Waiting for $.ajax request to complete

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im working on a d3 project which pulls in a json file using d3.json() and then passes the response to another function called update() that loops through an array and runs an ajax call on each item and returns the results.  I'm then trying to filter out all items that have false defined for the htrans property which is added in both the success and failed callback functions.  The issue I'm having is that the worldMap variable doesn't seem to have the htrans property when I'm executing the filter however if I console.log the element i can see it.  I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/jkeohan/pen/rWjave?editors=0010) to demo the functionality and have included the code below as well.

I know this has to do with returning promises and believe that worldMap might not be fully complete when I'm running the filter.  Any ideas on how to resolve this?

```
var url = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jkeohan/d77d5ab47e018defe48d54f59acefb65/raw/ff61673eff2e7bf610c5a426c5bd9ca46da2a9da/worldmap_geojson.json";

d3.json(url,function(err, world)  {
  var worldMap = update(world);
  worldMap.features.filter(function(d){
   if (d) { console.log(d.htrans); return d }; // this doesn't have the   htrans property
  });
  console.log(worldMap); // this displays the the htrans property
});

function update(obj){
  obj.features.filter(function(d,i) {
   var code = d.properties.iso_a2.toLowerCase();
   var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyAADudga5Cdk2QlHDWF8UAHQEy-Z_ikHw8&target=" + code + "&q=Hello";  
   return $.when(ajaxCall(url)).then(doneCB, failCB);

   function doneCB(data){
    d.hello = data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
    d.htrans = true;
    //console.log(d)
    return d;
   }

   function failCB(data){
    d.hello = "";
    d.htrans = false;
    //console.log(d)
    return d;
  };

  function ajaxCall(url) {
   return $.ajax(url);
  };

 });//filter
 return obj;
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a new promise for your worldMap.

```
d3.json(url,function(err, world)  {
  var worldMap = new Promise( function(resolve, reject){
         update(world, resolve,reject);
  })

  worldMap.then(//do something if worldMap promise resolves something good
      function(val){          
        val.features.filter(function(d){
            if (d) { 
              console.log(d.htrans);
            };
        });
      }
  )
  .catch(// if error happened inside promise
    function(reason) {
        console.log('reason');
  });

});
```

And resolve this promise like this:

```
function update(obj, resolve, reject){
  obj.features.filter(function(d,i) {
   var code = d.properties.iso_a2.toLowerCase();
   var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/language/translate/v2?key=AIzaSyAADudga5Cdk2QlHDWF8UAHQEy-Z_ikHw8&target=" + code + "&q=Hello";  
   return $.when(ajaxCall(url)).then(doneCB, failCB);

   function doneCB(data){
    d.hello = data.data.translations[0].translatedText;
    d.htrans = true;
    //console.log(d)
    resolve(d); //resolve on success
   }

   function failCB(data){
    d.hello = "";
    d.htrans = false;
    //console.log(d)
    reject(d); //reject on error
  };

  function ajaxCall(url) {
   return $.ajax(url);
  };

 });//filter
 return obj;
};
```

Take a look: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: @JoeKeohan glad you figured it out :)